# Something was dropped on my iPad Pro, and now the screen is black and won’t turn on?

Tags: ipad

So, my cleaning lady dropped something on my iPad Pro, and now the screen is black. HOWEVER, my problem is a bit... weirder. First off, when I first tried to open it I pressed the home button and saw light bleeding through a crack under the surface of the screen. As I’ve furthered my attempts, small, horizontal lines of light started appearing on the screen. Lastly, when I tried aimlessly tapping, I found that the touchscreen is functioning. In fact, I heard the sound the keys on the sign-in thingy make their usual noises.

I attempted using the age-old method of hard resetting it, but that did not work. Any answers are appreciated greatly.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue - can you bring it to an Apple Store for service?

Comment: Sounds like the LCD  itself is toast but the digitizer and backlight are somehow still working... hard to say exactly what but I would say that the only thing to do now is take in for repairs.

Comment: I would recommend you to unlock it and do an iTunes backup.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your backlight is broken. If you can, try to shine a flashlight at an angle and look for any images, or use it in a very dark room. If you can see anything being displayed, the backlight is broken.

Either way, you will have to take it in and get it repaired.